# Button binding in Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

I am wondering how to get my code to work. I have a class wich creates a popup window with buttons. Each button should be bound to subclass. But it doesnt work. What´s wrong with my code?

```
class chooser:
def __init__(self):
    None
def show(self,title,options=["NOTHING"],size=(.5,.5)):
    self.bts = {}
    self.response = False
    self.content = FloatLayout()
    self.content.pos_hint = {"y":0,"x":0}
    # create buttons
    pos_cntr = 0
    for opt in options:
        self.bts[pos_cntr] = Button(text=opt)
        self.bts[pos_cntr].size_hint = 1,float(1)/float(len(options))
        self.bts[pos_cntr].pos_hint = {"x":0,"y":pos_cntr}
        self.bts[pos_cntr].bind(on_press=self.canceldia)
        self.content.add_widget(self.bts[pos_cntr])
        print "bound"
        pos_cntr += float(1)/float(len(options))
    self.pop = Popup(title=title,content=self.content,auto_dismiss=False)
    self.pop.size_hint = size
    self.pop.open()
def canceldia(self,instance):
    print "closing"
    self.response = instance.text
    self.pop.dismiss()
def getresponse(self):
    return self.response
```

I have imported all needed modules.

I execute it so:

```
c = chooser()
c.show("hello","world",["welcome","close","nothing","example"])
```

I have create a root widget. The popup works fine and all is created nice but the buttons are not bound. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you always reference `self.bts[pos_cntr]`, so you override it in every iteration. How about this?

```
for idx, opt in enumerate(options):
    self.bts[idx] = Button(text=opt)
    self.bts[idx].size_hint = 1,float(1)/float(len(options))
    self.bts[idx].pos_hint = {"x":0,"y":pos_cntr}
    self.bts[idx].bind(on_press=self.canceldia)
    self.content.add_widget(self.bts[idx])
```

Comment: Tip me by upvoting :o)

Comment: Sorry. I can't upvote you now. I do not have enough reputation. When i have enough i will upvote you ;)